# should I check error each step on a redis multi transaction?

Tags: go, redis, redigo

should I check error each step on a redis multi transaction? if some error happen, was it mean, the release command will also return error?

eg. can I :

```
 conn.Do("multi")
 conn.Do("set", "mm", "xx")
 reply, err := conn.Do("exec")
 if err != nil {
      ....
  }
```

or, should i :

```
  _, err := conn.Do("multi")
 if err != nil {
     ....
     return
 }
_, err := conn.Do("set", "mm", "xx")
if err != nil {
     ....
    return
 }
 reply, err := conn.Do("exec")
if err != nil {
    ....
   return
 }
```

Comment: Depends on the implementation of the `conn`'s `Do` method.

Comment: It is better not to ignore errors. But if you don't want to write this code snippet every time. Create a function to check error.

Comment: in that case you can t create helper function to check for error, 'cause you still have to return if there is an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To transact, you need to `Send()` each command, and only `Do()` the EXEC. Error checking should be done for the `Do()` only, like so:

```
conn.Send("MULTI")
conn.Send("SET", "foo", "bar")
...
reply, err := conn.Do("EXEC")
if err != nil {
    ...
}
...
```